# Adding a JPanel to a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jdialog

I have two classes - one representing a `JFrame` and the other representing a `JPanel`. On the `JPanel` I have `JComponents` that I would want to use in capturing user input. On the `JFrame` I have a `JButton` that displays the `JPanel` on `JDialog` when a user hit it. Below is the code to achieve this:

A class that is extending a `JFrame`.

```
public class ControlPanel extends JFrame {

public JButton display;

ControlPanel() {
    this.createUI();

    // button action
    this.display.addActionListener((ActionEvent) -> {
        AddUser ad = new AddUser();
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this,
                Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.setSize(300, 300);
        dialog.add(ad);

    });
}

public void createUI() {

    this.setTitle("Dispalying a JPanel on JDialog");
    this.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

    this.display = new JButton("Display");
    this.add(new JLabel("North", JLabel.CENTER), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(this.display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(new JLabel("South", JLabel.CENTER), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(new JLabel("East"), BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.add(new JLabel("West"), BorderLayout.WEST);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ControlPanel cp = new ControlPanel();
    }
 }
```

A class that is extending a `JPanel`.

**This panel is the one that I would want to be added on to the** `JDialog`.

```
public class AddUser extends JPanel {

public AddUser() {
    this.prepareUI();

}

public void prepareUI() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4, 5, 5));

    this.add(new JLabel("Label1"));
    this.add(new JLabel("Label2"));
    this.add(new JLabel("Label2"));
    this.add(new JLabel("Label2"));

    /* Code to test if the panel is displaying fine.
     * The panel is displaying fine.
     * JFrame fr = new JFrame();
    fr.setVisible(true);
    fr.setSize(300, 300);
    fr.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    fr.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    fr.pack();*/
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AddUser ad = new AddUser();
  }
}
```

**NOTE** : I am doing this because I want the panel to be **modal** - the user must not interact with components on the `JFrame` before he is finished with the `JPanel`.

**Problem** : The `Jpanel` [this one:`AddUser ad = new AddUser();`] is not showing when the `JDialog` is shown.

**Question** : What went wrong with my code and how do I solve it?

Below is the out put when the `display` button is clicked.

[image]

Comment: Call JDialog#pack and JDialog#setVisible (in that order) AFTER you've added your panel...

Comment: @MadProgrammer That solved it, allow me to say thanks - I was looking for this since yesterday.

Comment: Welcome to the forest, watch out for the trees